# Word for books of sarcastic type

Tags: single-word-requests, books

Is there a a specific word for a book with a sarcastic theme? I am thinking of writing a book on the world of magic of witches and warlocks but in reality it is making fun of their beliefs. For example the section on herbs and potions deal with the recreationsal drugs man takes daily in life. Enslaving the apprentice deals with regular trials of working under a boss or company etc. Just wondering if there is a specific word for this type of book so I can research it more....

Comment: Most appropriate might be to classify the works as 'sarcasm' (a sub-group under 'satire,' maybe.)

Answer (score 5):

**Satire**

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satire):

> Satire is a genre of literature, and sometimes graphic and performing
>   arts, in which vices, follies, abuses, and shortcomings are held up to
>   ridicule, ideally with the intent of shaming individuals,
>   corporations, government or society itself, into improvement.
>   Although satire is usually meant to be humorous, its greater purpose
>   is often constructive social criticism, using wit as a weapon and as a
>   tool to draw attention to both particular and wider issues in society.

***"the crude satire seems to be directed at the fashionable protest singers of the time"***

According to [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/satire):

> **Satire**:
>
> The use of humour, irony, exaggeration, or ridicule to expose and
>   criticize people’s stupidity or vices, particularly in the context of
>   contemporary politics and other topical issues.

Comment: "A feature of satire is strong irony or sarcasm." Satire is broader than sarcasm.

Comment: "The distinctive quality of sarcasm is present in the spoken word and manifested chiefly by vocal inflection, whereas satire and irony arising originally as literary and rhetorical forms, are exhibited in the organization or structuring of either language or literary material."

Comment: @Kris - Please cite your sources.

Comment: @ErikKowal *ibid.*

Comment: @Kris - Is that *ibid.* Wikipedia or *ibid.* Oxford Dictionaries? If both, which citation comes from which source?

Comment: It's interesting that the words satire and sarcasm, are difficult to define, are used widely and loosely, and are the sort of word where you can challenge someone who has just used it to define it and they know what it means but can't put their finger on it!

Comment: @joe your point being?

Comment: What up Grace.  I don't have, do not need to, and can't be bothered making points. It's just an interesting point.  BTW it occurs to me the old film "Reality Bites" (Winona Ryder right - hell she must be like 85 now) has a joke on exactly that, in the film.

Comment: While we're still waiting for @Kris to confirm whether his/her citations are taken from Wikipedia, Oxford Dictionaries or even elsewhere, I'll take this opportunity to assert that sarcasm is every bit as present in the world of the written word as in the spoken. I'm not sure what exactly "satire [...][is] exhibited in the organization or structuring of either language or literary material" is actually supposed to mean, but I can at least tell that it fails to reflect the fact that words on a page can  convey a sarcastic attitude through their tone of voice just as well as speech can.

Comment: @Kris - Quite true, but my underlying point is that sources are supposed to be cited here, as you have so often reminded other people.

Comment: Not necessarily in case of comments, esp., where it's that obvious.

Comment: @Kris - But it's *not* that obvious. That's the point. Being informed whether quoted text comes from Wikipedia or the OUP makes a difference to the reader's perception of how much credence to give to it. This applies just as much when the quoted fragment is supplied in a comment as when it appears in an official answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Parody**

In the OP's example the theme of witches, magic, apprentices and potions is imitated, ridiculed and taken to excess for comic effect.

The [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parody) says:

> A parody (/ˈpærədi/; also called spoof, send-up or lampoon), in use,
> is an imitative work created to imitate, or comment on and
> trivialize[citation needed] an original work, its subject, author,
> style, or some other target, by means of satiric or ironic imitation [...]
>
> [**Examples of parody in literature and cinema**]
>
> Sometimes the reputation of a parody outlasts the reputation of what
> is being parodied. For example, **Don Quixote**, which mocks the
> traditional knight errant tales, is much better known than the novel
> that inspired it, Amadis de Gaula
>
> The British comedy group Monty Python is also famous for its
> parodies, for example, the King Arthur spoof Monty Python and the **Holy
> Grail** (1974), and the Jesus satire **Life of Brian** (1979). In the 1980s
> there came another team of parodists including David Zucker, Jim
> Abrahams and Jerry Zucker. Their most popular films are the **Airplane!**,
> **Hot Shots!** and **Naked Gun** series.

Comment: I wouldn't say this was exactly a wrong answer, but it somewhat misses the mark. This is because a parody is usually (though admittedly not exclusively) taken to refer to a send-up of an *artistic work* (book, film, play etc.) rather than of a real-life phenomenon. So in the case in point, a *parody* would lampoon somebody else's *artistic treatment* of magic and witches, rather than the real-life practices and practitioners. A better answer is *lampoon, send-up* or *satire*. (Incidentally, those terms can also be applied to artistic works, which means that they can be applied more widely.)

Comment: @ErikKowal fair and valid point, I offered an alternative answer. However, the OP could be thinking of the Harry Potter series, plenty of wizards, witches, potions and apprentices there to take the mickey out of :)

Comment: User is going to make fun of the fictional "world of magic" .. ie it is a parody of Harry Potter.

Comment: @JoeBlow I wouldn't go as far as saying that the OP has in mind a Harry Potter parody, but it's a plausible (and contemporary) one. If the OP would like to confirm that would be helpful.

Comment: Quite right ML, @Erik - I just realised the OP may have been referring to, you know, those actual people who "practice magic" and the like (err .. goths, wickens, whatever!)  Sorry about that.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell the difference. I've read that satire is mocking to incite and parody is just for humor. I'm am simply writing a book for humor but on some subtle level, I am mocking the current generation though not really. However, since mockery is not the main basis of my book(simply equating our current lifestyle with things in the world of magicke) I think I will stick to the concept of parody. I do not wish to mock.

Comment: Anyway, the specifics are not important. I now have two words to research with.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you are looking for is *satire*.